# Storing console.timeEnd values in javascript array

Tags: javascript, timer, console

I am trying to record reaction times using console.Time() and console.timeEnd() and store the values in an array.

The correct values were showing up in the console, but they are failing to be stored in global variables I have crated.

I am trying to use two functions, one which starts the timer on body load, and another which ends the timer once the user presses the first key. The console will write reasonable values (e.g., 1200.30 milliseconds), but the array will return either a blank value or NaN (changes based on what I try).

Note: I tried performance.now() and date.now() and both had problems. Performance.now() did not work with my 2 functions, and date.now() returned nonsensical values. I'd like to use the console timer since it seems very accurate and to be working, I just cannot store the final value.

```
<script>
var fkpl = "";
var time1= "";
var time2= "";

function BodyLoad(){
 var time1 = console.time("fkpl");
 fkpl = time2-time1;
 dataArray = [userID, cue, target, response, fkpl];
 document.getElementById("CopyTrial").innerHTML = dataArray;
}

function recordKeyPress() {
 var executed = false;
 return function(){
   if (!executed){
     var time2 = console.timeEnd("fkpl");
     executed = true;
     }
  }
}
</script>
```

**UPDATE**
I got the code to work using both Date.now() and/or performance.now(). I will stick with performance.now() as it is working nicely.

```
time1 = Math.round(performance.now());
time2 = Math.round(performance.now());
fkpl = (time2-time1);
```

As an aside, I *could not* get any values recorded from console.timeEnd. It simply would never store the value inside a variable. I tried making sure they were global variables, but that did not help. I think somehow the information that is output to the console is not readable / is not able to be stored or accessed without some serious workarounds (this is just my guess).

Anyways, I do think part of my problem was a mixture of not having global variables defined, and also executing the function with each keypress instead of just the first key press. Glad it's working now, but I'd love someone to weigh in one why it's impossible to read from the console!!

Comment: What were the problems with Performance.now and Date.now?

Comment: If you want `time1` and `time2` to be global, don't use `var` with those variables within your functions.

Comment: @positlabs Performance.now() gave me values in a range from 110-150. I am assuming that's milliseconds, which is clearly wrong. One possibility is that perhaps each keypress started the function over, overwriting the time2 value until it reached 0. By then, the 100 milliseconds just represented a delay between my other code executing? Not sure, but I'll check. Date.now kept giving astronomically large values (e.g., 10201203102301).